# Create variables without the createPages API in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I was wondering if I could use variables that I create with the createPages API outside the component template.

My scenario is that I create a variable like this:

```
            pages.forEach(page => {
                createPage({
                    path: `${page.slug}`,
                    component: path.resolve(`src/templates/page-template.js`),
                    context: {
                        title: page.title // My Variable
                    },
                })
```

Now, in my `page-template.js` file I import a component that holds an external graphql query that is not included in the `page-template.js` file but I want to use variables in the query.

Can I create variables without the createPages API in Gatsby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this via the `pageContext` prop. E.g:

```
const YourComponent = ({ pageContext }) => 
  <SomeOtherComponent title={pageContext.title} />
```

This assumes that `SomeOtherComponent` is running this GraphQL query against an external DB, not the local Gatsby GraphQL server, though.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That helped me a lot.